# Rewrite URL with Query is not working, why?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect the following URL:

```
https://domain.de/cms/front_content.php?idcat=650&lang=1 to https://otherdomain.de/preview.html
```

I wrote the htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^idcat=650&lang=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^cms/front_content\.php$ https://otherdomain.de/preview.html? [R,L]
```

It does not work for me, why?
Its a CMS, both Domains are in it.

Comment: your example mentions idcat=65**0** but your rule contains idcat=65**3**: typo? The .htaccess is located in the DocumentRoot of domain.de? With an `AllowOverride` not to `None` ?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. The .htaccess is located in the DocumentRoot of domain.de (Both Domains using the same CMS = same .htaccess). AllowOverride != None.
Still not working...

Comment: Is there any other rule before this one?

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 different rules before. After repositioning, the above redirect works well!
@thanks to julp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).